# Issue Customizing Bootstrap Menu

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to create a circular border for a font awesome and this is what i get
[image]

This is within the page header. I intend to zoom in the buttons when the screen size is being resized.

```
 .circle-icon {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle !important;
padding: 30px;
border-color: #fff; 
border-width:1px; 
border-style:solid;}
```

This is only part of the menu code

```
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8">
            <div class="row icon-bar">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <a class="active" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tag circle-icon"></i>
                        <div style="font-size:14px !important; padding: 7px !important;">
                            Voucher

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-qrcode circle-icon"></i>
                        <div style="font-size:14px !important; padding: 7px !important;">
                            Redeem

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding: 30px;
Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you try also playing with different values (or none) for vertical-align and line-height? Try removing them first